# Android TextWatcher read SQL data with multi threading. how close old thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, textwatcher

I have a function that connects to the database with create new thread because search function is heavy job.

```
textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(final Editable editable) {
        search(textView.getText().toString());
    }
});

public void search(String word) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            this.wordsList = db.getWordsList(word); //big job
            .
            .
            .
        }
    }).start();
}
```

but the program slows down when these codes are executed several times in a short period of time. The program hangs by executing the above code several times.

So I want to close the previous thread and then open new thread. in fact I don't need the results of previous threads so I want close them for increasing program speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code and solved my problem :

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.execute(new Runnable() { public void run() { /* do something */ } });
```